# R if both condition satisfied

Tags: r, if-statement

I need to create a if statement if any of the 2 columns has null/na value, then stop running script. However I have trouble to set the if statement to be Both, so my question is how to set if statement AND condition

Here is an example:

```
x=data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=NA, c=c("re", "de", "oo"))
```

because column b has na value, the following code `any(is.na(x$b))`will give a TRUE logic

> [1] TRUE

Column C has value, so the following code `any(is.na(x$c))` gives a FALSE logic

> [1] FALSE

however, when I combine both condition together `any(is.na(x$b))&any(is.na(x$c))`, the result should be TRUE as col B has na, but the result is actually FALSE, any idea how to write the right code please?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Use or `|` instead of and `&`

Comment: you need an OR, rather than AND.  i.e. use `|`

Comment: The easiest way would be to just do `any(is.na(x[,c("a", "b")]))`. If there is an NA in the the 2-column df, it'll return TRUE.

Comment: wow, all answers are perfect,thank you for solving my question!